# Heap/ PermGen setting issues in tomcat under eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, garbage-collection, jvm, permgen

A colleague has the following setting in Eclipse / Tomcat run parameters, and complains of out of heap memory all the time:

```
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-Xmx1024m
```

If I understand this correctly, both the `max PermGen` and `max Heap` are each 1 GB.  Since `PermGen` is a special part of the Heap, this amounts to allocating all of the heap to `PermGen`. Is this correct?

Per [Perm Space vs Heap Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848669/perm-space-vs-heap-space), I might be correct.  Would this be causing the issue?

Per [Is Java PermGen Space Part of Total VM Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223809/is-java-permgen-space-part-of-the-total-vm-memory), my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable GC logging, once the Eclipse crashes again, you will see the cause of the problem, the logs will show you the size of PermGen.

GC logging :`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -showversion`

Considering the PermGen being part of the Heap or not, this actually depends on the version of the Hotspot you are running. The GC algorithm controls the size of the PermGen, so even though you set MAX=1GB, it may never grow that big and you can still get OOM because of some other issue.

Answer (score 3):

you are right. >512MB are spent for PermGen and <512MB are available for Heap

use JVisualVM shipped with any Sun/Oracle JVM to connect to the running eclipse process and check the actual situation